# A milk case contains 5 quarts of milk, only 4 of which are fresh. You select 2 randomly and without replacements.

Tags: probability, statistics

**A milk case contains 5 quarts of milk, only 4 of which are fresh. You select 2 randomly and without replacements. 
A) Find a sample space and assign probabilities to sample points.**

S = {(Fresh, Fresh), (Fresh, Not Fresh)}

P(F,F) = 4C2/5C2 = 6/10

P(F,NF) = (4C1) (1C1)/ 5C2 = (4)(1)/10 = 4/10

**B)Find the distribution table of the random variable X representing the number of fresh quarts among the two selected ones.**

Not sure how to put in a table, so I'll just write down the values I have

X=0 f(X)=0

X=1 f(x)=4/10

X=2 f(x)=6/10

Could someone confirm that what I did is right? Thank you!

Comment: What you did is one of many correct answers.  Your choice of sample space, although convenient, will not be useful if the problem goes on to a an additional part later asking something about order of selection such as "*what is the probability that the second quart selected was fresh given that the first was also fresh*".  That being said, it is a moot point if this is the only question related to this example.

Comment: Thanks :) This is in fact the only question related to this example.

Comment: Here is a [Mathjax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for better typesetting of these formulas

Answer (score 0):

Comment: Your distribution table is correct.

For future reference, $X$ is a *hypergeometric* random variable.
$$P(X = k) = \frac{{4\choose k}{1 \choose 2-k}}{{5\choose 2}},$$
for $k = 0, 1, 2.$ Note that ${1 \choose 2} = 0.$

Distribution table from R statistical software:

```
k = 0:2;  pdf = dhyper(k, 4, 1, 2);  cbind(k, pdf)
     k pdf
  ## 0 0.0
  ## 1 0.4
  ## 2 0.6
```